# Firefox flashes white on title updates

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I am writing some code to automatically update some data on a page.

I have written this function to show the user when this will occur, however the page flashes white every now and again on the title update. I have tested on chrome and IE and the flash does not occur.

There is no other function on a timer as I have not yet written the update function, hence the alert("updated")

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    window.start-=1;
    var minutes = Math.floor(window.start/60);
    var seconds = window.start % 60;
    if(seconds<10) seconds = "0"+seconds;
    if(window.start<0){
        alert("updated");
        window.start=300;
    }
    document.title = "update in - "+minutes+":"+seconds; 
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. FF 33.1 (custom theme)

Comment: weird, it may be a plugin issue?  i am using firefox 31.4.0. unfortunately an update is not possible

Comment: Can you try it on a different computer? Or a clean FF? Tested again with FF 35.0.1 and no flashes.

Comment: unfortunately it seems to be an internal problem, my company all have the same FF (plugins inc) and computers. so testing on a colleagues computer shows the same flash of white. I will have to work around it by removing the timer and just setting to update every 5 minutes.

Thanks for your help anyway, much appreciated